# How to put error-label inside a stylized div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

Im using jquery validate...  the option wrapper: "div" creates the "error label" inside a div nice... I want that div with a class like this:

```
$(".selector").validate({
    wrapper: "div"
    ....
})
```

That returns:

```
<div style="">
    <label for="email" generated="true" class="error" style="">Type real email</label>
</div>
```

I want this:

```
<div class="errorClass">
    <label for="email" generated="true" class="error" style="">Type real email</label>
</div>
```

Or I'll be happy if you teach me to put any stile inside that div, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think you could achieve this by just doing this.

```
$(".selector").validate({ wrapper: "div" ....}).addClass("errorClass");
```